Why does Conrad show a t-shirt at the end of The Game?
At the end of the movie, The Game (1997 film), Conrad, Nicholas's brother shows a t-shirt which says:

I WAS DRUGGED AND LEFT FOR DEAD IN MEXICO - AND ALL I GOT WAS THIS STUPID T-SHIRT

What does it mean? What purpose does that message serve to Nicholas, because the t-shirt was shown to him?

is it because, maybe, Conrad was left in a hospital in Mexico, for he was drugged. And he didn't like it because his brother Nicholas did not come to visit and only sent a t-shirt; and later Conrad printed this t-shirt with that message......???

It's meant as a joke.  Like, when you see the t-shirts that say "My Grandma went to Hawaii and all I got was this stupid t-shirt"

It's meant as a joke, as such tee-shirts have been around for ages.
A search (then click the images tab) shows tens of similar shirts.
In the movie, after all Nicholas went through, and finally threw himself from the roof of a building, the funny present is here to remind him that there are more things left from a trip than the mere souvenir you might bring back...
